# FullCalendar.io and Infinite for Loop trying to show elements

Tags: lightning-web-components, fullcalendar

I am new to LWC so i maybe do a common mistake. I have a LWC with implementing fullCalendarJS.io and I have customized the default solution to get via apex controller the events related to my org and display them to the calendar. The problem is that when i put an iteration in my html, it seems to get at infinite loop whereas if i erase the for:each section template, it does not have any problems. Is it the fact that due to @track element it always changes and it keeps rerendering? I cannot understand and any help would be really appreciated cause i am really stuck with this. Code below:
HTML

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-card">
    <template for:each={eventsList} for:item="evt">
      <p key={evt.Id}>{evt.Subject}</p>
    </template>
    <lightning-button
      label="New Event"
      title="New Event"
      onclick={createNewEvent}
    ></lightning-button>
    <div class="fullcalendar" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from "lwc";
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import FullCalendarJS from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/FullCalendarJS";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
import { encodeDefaultFieldValues } from "lightning/pageReferenceUtils";
import getMyEvents from "@salesforce/apex/fullCalendarController.getEventsForCurrentUser";
import { RecordFieldDataType } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";

export default class FullCalendarJs extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
  @wire(getMyEvents) myEvents;
  @track eventsList = [];
  currentEvent;

  renderedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
      // First step: load FullCalendar core
      loadStyle(this, FullCalendarJS + "/packages/core/main.css"),
      loadScript(this, FullCalendarJS + "/packages/core/main.js")
    ])
      .then(() => {
        // Second step: Load the plugins in a new promise
        Promise.all([
          loadStyle(this, FullCalendarJS + "/packages/daygrid/main.css"),
          loadScript(this, FullCalendarJS + "/packages/daygrid/main.js"),
          loadStyle(this, FullCalendarJS + "/packages/timegrid/main.css"),
          loadScript(this, FullCalendarJS + "/packages/timegrid/main.js"),
          loadScript(this, FullCalendarJS + "/packages/interaction/main.js")
        ]).then(() => {
          // Third step: calls your calendar builder once the plugins have been also loaded
          this.initialiseFullCalendar();
          console.log("initialize!");
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Catch any error while loading the scripts here
      });
  }

  initialiseFullCalendar() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log("begin");

    //@ggalaios 03-04-2020 If events not null or undefined...
    if (this.myEvents) {
      console.log("inside if");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < this.myEvents.data.length; i++) {
        console.log("inside for");
        //@ggalaios 03-04-2020 iterate through each event
        this.currentEvent = {
          id: this.myEvents.data[i].Id,
          start: this.myEvents.data[i].StartDateTime,
          end: this.myEvents.data[i].EndDateTime,
          title: this.myEvents.data[i].Subject
        };
        this.eventsList.push(this.currentEvent);
        console.log("after push!");
      }
    }
    console.log(this.eventsList);
    const ele = this.template.querySelector("div.fullcalendar");
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log("ele >>> " + ele);
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(ele, {
      header: {
        left: "prev,next,today",
        center: "title",
        right:
          "timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGrid,timegrid"
      },
      plugins: [
        "interaction",
        "resourceDayGrid",
        "resourceTimeGrid",
        "dayGrid",
        "timegrid"
      ],
      events: this.eventsList,
      defaultView: "dayGridWeek"
    });

    calendar.render();
    console.log(this.eventsList.data);
    console.log("Rendering");
  }

  createNewEvent() {
    console.log("called");
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: "standard__objectPage",
      attributes: {
        objectApiName: "Event",
        actionName: "new"
      },
      state: {
        nooverride: "1"
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is trying to update **eventsList** in each iteration and the variable is tracked which might be causing the issue... Try updating the code to

```
 let newEventList = [] 
 this.myEvents.data.forEach(ele => {
   newEventList.push({
      id: ele.Id,
      start: ele.StartDateTime,
      end: ele.EndDateTime,
      title: ele.Subject
   });
 });
 this.eventsList = newEventList.length != 0 ? [...newEventList] : [];
```

Comment: Abhijith E thank you for the reply and the suggestion. Could you please explain the last line of the code you suggest ?

Comment: It’s just assigning value to the event list conditionally